# Mudar volume de um arquivo WAV em C

Tags: c, áudio

Estou tentando fazer uma mudança de volume num arquivo WAV que simplesmente não entendo porque não da certo. Sou iniciante e peço a vcs ajuda pra entender o pq do volume ficar muito estourado e ruido quando eu tento diminuir o volume.
Basicamente se eu tento aumentar o volume funciona bem, mas quando eu coloco por exemplo "factor = 0.5" que tem a intenção de diminuir o volume do audio pela metade não funciona.
OBS: já é dito que o arquivo em questão tem o cabeçalho com 44 bytes e as samples 16 bits

```
    // TODO: Copy header from input file to output file
    // HEADER_SIZE = tamanho do cabeçalho do input 
    // BYTE = uint8_t
BYTE bytes[HEADER_SIZE];

fread(bytes,sizeof(BYTE),HEADER_SIZE,input);
fwrite(bytes,sizeof(BYTE),HEADER_SIZE,output);


// TODO: Read samples from input file and write updated data to output file
// BYTE16 = uint16_t
BYTE16 tbytes;

fseek(input,44,0);
fseek(output,44,0);

while(fread(&tbytes, sizeof(BYTE16),1,input))
{
    tbytes = (BYTE16)(tbytes * factor);
    fwrite(&tbytes, sizeof(BYTE16), 1, output);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Olhando o seu código me parece que vc simplesmente está multiplicando `BYTES` pelo fator ... não é assim que funciona !!! no seu exemplo acima vc está manipulando os Bytes, isso não quer dizer q esteja alterando a amplitude do áudio da maneira correta, na verdade no seu exemplo acima vc está destruindo seu áudio rsrs, não importa qual seja o fator, se algo for diferente de `1` vc está simplesmente alterando os bytes e não a amplitude ...

A maneira correta é primeiro converter `bytes` em `short int` ou `float point` dessa maneira vc terá seus dados em [PCM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula%C3%A7%C3%A3o_por_c%C3%B3digo_de_pulsos), com esses dados em mãos vc poderá "vislumbrar" da amplitude do sinal para poder manipulá-lo,  aconselho deixar os dados em `float point` é o mais sensato pois no seu exemplo vc está multiplicando por um número que não é inteiro ...

Depois de manipular a amplitude vc terá que converter `float point` para `endian little` e escrever no arquivo de saída ... ví que vc tbm não fez nenhuma checagem no cabeçalho do arquivo `wav`, em teoria vc só copiou os `44` primeiros bytes do cabeçalho existente para o novo arquivo que está escrevendo, para alterar amplitude/volume do sinal realmente não interfere na reescrita de cabeçalho, só pra constar segue a arquitetura de como os arquivos de áudios em `wav` funcionam, fica claro que os `44` primeiros bytes do arquivo são os campos do cabeçalho do áudio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só para testar, na imagem acima fica claro que os `4` primeiros `bytes` do cabeçalho do arquivo deve formar a palavra `RIFF`, vamos escrever algo bem simples para testar o conceito:

```
/* 
gcc teste.c -o teste

teste inicial do cabeçalho

*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

FILE *fp;
int HEADER_SIZE=44;

if(argc < 2) {

    printf("Usage: %s <file.wav>", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
}

fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

uint8_t bytes[HEADER_SIZE];

fread(bytes,sizeof(uint8_t),HEADER_SIZE,fp);

printf("%c",bytes[0]);
printf("%c",bytes[1]);
printf("%c",bytes[2]);
printf("%c",bytes[3]);

exit(0);
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parece que estamos no caminho certo, então bora manipular o q realmente interessa que são as informações após o byte `44`, mas antes eu acho importante ter os dados do tamanho do áudio, e para isso podemos pegar os valores contidos no cabeçalho, segundo a imagem acima está entre o byte `40` e `44` (Subchunk2Size), para fazer isso vou voltar o ponteiro para caminhar novamente a partir da posição correta `fseek(fp,40,0);` precisamos extrair os próximos `4` bytes que contenha a  informação `fread(&tam_audio, 4, 1, fp)`; a variável `tam_audio/2` irá possuir com exatidão a quantidade de amostras existente dentro do seu arquivo `wav`, então agora podemos caminhar por cada amostra enquanto convertemos ela de `short int` para `float point` essa conversão é feita ao dividir o valor short int atual pelo valor máximo possível de um [`short int(32768)`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-c/) após fazer esses passos agora é só multiplicar pelo seu fator de volume desejado...

OK estamos quase lá, agora vc precisa voltar os valores de `float point` para `short int` e escrever no seu arquivo de saída, mas não sem antes controlar os limites, esses limites permitem que vc grampeie o áudio (Clipp)  ou seja, por exemplo se vc multiplicar seu sinal de áudio por um `volume = 10` ou seja dez vez mais amplitude/volume do que o arquivo original, se vc fizer isso sem tratar os limites da amplitude vc terá amostras extrapolando os limites do `short int` e isso irá causar ruídos indesejados no seu áudio, bommm chega de escrever, segue o código que implementa tudo q está escrito aqui ...

```
/* 
gcc teste.c -o teste
ederwander testes para o SO
Altere a variável volume para mudar a amplitude no wav
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

float PCM_sinal_alterado;
int HEADER_SIZE=44;
float volume = 2;
float *PCM_sinal;
long tam_audio;
short data;
FILE *fp2;
FILE *fp;
int n;


if(argc < 2) {

    printf("Usage: %s <file.wav>", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
}

fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

fp2 = fopen("alterado.wav", "wb");

uint8_t bytes[HEADER_SIZE];

//copiando o cabeçalho original para o novo arquivo
fread(bytes,sizeof(uint8_t),HEADER_SIZE,fp);
fwrite(bytes,sizeof(uint8_t),HEADER_SIZE,fp2);

/*
//nao vou usar nada disso agora...
printf("%c",bytes[0]);
printf("%c",bytes[1]);
printf("%c",bytes[2]);
printf("%c",bytes[3]);
*/


//voltando o ponteiro para o byte 40 (quero saber a quantidade de amostras existente no áudio)
fseek(fp,40,0);

fread(&tam_audio, 4, 1, fp);
//tamanho real tam_audio / 2

PCM_sinal = calloc(tam_audio/2, sizeof(float));

for (n = 0; n < tam_audio/2; n++)
{

        //convertendo para float point e aplicando mudança de volume
        fread(&data, 2, 1, fp); 
        PCM_sinal[n] = ((float)data / 32768.0) * volume;
    
        //convertendo para short int novamente e escrevendo no novo arquivo
        //clippando o áudio para não extrapolar os limites 
        PCM_sinal_alterado = (PCM_sinal[n] + 1.0) / 2.0 * 32768.0 * 2.0;
    
        if (PCM_sinal_alterado  > (2.0 * 32768.0)-1 )
        {
            PCM_sinal_alterado = (2.0 * 32768.0)-1 ; 
        }
        else if (PCM_sinal_alterado  < 0.0)
        {
            PCM_sinal_alterado  = 0.0; 
        }
    
        data = (short)(PCM_sinal_alterado  + 0.5) - 32768;
        fwrite(&data, 2, 1, fp2);
}

fclose(fp);
fclose(fp2);
free(PCM_sinal);

puts("Feito...");
exit(0);
}
```

Ahh algo importante, é óbvio que tudo isso é mt simples e isso só irá funcionar para arquivos wav em 16bits e em mono ...

Answer (score -2):

Na verdade o problema não é no C e sim no conceito do audio, quando você muda a amplitude, seja por meio da codificação ou por meio de uma mesa de som, você muda a dinâmica da audio.
Quando você amplificou (aumentou) o que ocorreu foi uma mudança no formato da onda que produz a amplificação, quando você passa as mesmas ondas diversas vezes pelo algoritmo a precisão do calculo vai inserindo esses ruídos.
Na verdade, o fator de alteração para mais ou para menos, deve ser menor a cada passagem, ao invés de usa um fator 0,5 tenta usar 0,8 ou 0,75 e passa 2 vezes o loop que a interferência deve se tornar menor.....

Comment: Mesmo colocando 0.9 ou 0.8 não muda nada, o audio fica extremamente alto , estourado e ruído